# Laravel: Undefined value on image upload

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

First Laravel Project. I building a feature where I can upload an image. Everything what I did is based on [this PDF](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/laravel/laravel_tutorial.pdf) (page 98-101)

**My blade.php**

```
<?php echo Form::open(array('url' =>'/product/imgedit','files'=>'true'));
echo 'Adj meg egy új képet';
echo Form::file('image');
echo Form::submit('Upload File');
echo Form::close();?>
```

**My router**

```
Route::get('product/{id}/imgedit', 'InventoryController@imgreq');
Route::post('product/imgedit', 'InventoryController@imgupl');
```

**My Controller:**

```
public function imgreq($id)
{
    $product = DB::select('select * FROM inventory WHERE barcode = ?', [$id]);;

    return view('productimgupl', ['product' => $product]);
}

public function imgupl()
{
    $file = $request->file('image');
    //Display File Name
    echo 'File Name: ' . $file->getClientOriginalName();
    echo '<br>';
    //Display File Extension
    echo 'File Extension: ' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
    echo '<br>';
    //Display File Real Path
    echo 'File Real Path: ' . $file->getRealPath();
    echo '<br>';
    //Display File Size
    echo 'File Size: ' . $file->getSize();
    echo '<br>';
    //Display File Mime Type
    echo 'File Mime Type: ' . $file->getMimeType();
    //Move Uploaded File
    $destinationPath = '/media/productimg/';
    $file->move($destinationPath, $file->getClientOriginalName());
}
```

**Error message:**

> ErrorException in InventoryController.php line 28: Undefined variable:
>   request

What I did wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bring in the `Request` object in your method's argument. Like so:

```
public function imgupl(Request $request) {
// code...
}
```

Then you may use `$request` in the method.

By default Laravel includes this class when you use `php artisan make:controller` by inserting it at the top of your Controller with this line: `use Illuminate\Http\Request;`. All you are doing is casting the `Request` object to a variable named `$request` for use in that method.

Hope this helps!

Comment: No problem. Glad to help.